# How do I calculate the average of the first 12 cells with values in a range over 100 cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I calculate the average of the first 12 cells with values in a range over 100 cells?
I am calculating golf averages and not everyone plays the same amount of times.  I need to show the average of the previous 12 rounds played.

Comment: What is in the other cells? You should provide some example data.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: It's beter to share us with a sample for more details in later.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you do not provide any sample data, I constructed some random data in the range `A1:B101`. One approach is using `AVERAGE()`, `TAKE()`, and `FILTER()`,

The following generic formula can be used to compute the average over the last X values.

```
=AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER(data,ISNUMBER(data)),-n))
```

With your specific data and requiremenets of 12 days this looks as follows:

```
=AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER($B$1:$B$101,ISNUMBER($B$1:$B$101)),-12))
```

First, you `FILTER()` only numeric values from your data, i.e., you ignore blank and `#N/A` values. Based on the filtered data you `TAKE()` only the last n values, i.e., 12 in your case, and lastly, you compute the `AVERAGE()` across these data points.

The example data looks as follows for the first 15 rows. The day sequence runs from 1 to 100 and for the player I created random values between 1 and 10 using `RANDBETWEEN(1,10)` and kept some cells blank randomly.

| day | player1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 |  |
| 6 | 10 |
| 7 |  |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 |  |
| 11 |  |
| 12 | 6 |
| 13 |  |
| 14 |  |
| 15 | 1 |